# Kafka avro serialization with schema evolution

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to build a kakfa pipeline which will read JSON input data into Kafka topic.
I am using AVRO serialization with schema registry, as my schema gets changed on regular basis.
As of now GenericRecord is used to parse the schema.
But I recently came to know that avro-tools are available to read schema and generate Java classes which can be used to create Producer Code.
I am confused choose between these two options.
Can you please suggest me which one is better, as my schema gets frequently changed?

Answer (score 1):

> avro-tools are available to read schema and generate java classes which can be used to create Producer Code

They create specific Avro classes, not Producer code, but regarding the question. Both will work.

The way I see it

- `GenericRecord` - Think of it as a `HashMap<String, Object>`. As a consumer need to know the fields to get. If, as a producer or schema creator, you are not able to send your classes as a library to your consumers, this is the essentially the best you can get. I believe you'll always be able to get the latest data, though (all possible fields can be accessed by a `get("fieldname")` call.  [See example here](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/4.0.x/kafka-clients/consumer/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/consumer/ConsumerLogic.java#L43)
- `SpecificRecord` (what `avro-tools` generates) - It is just a generated class with getter methods and builder objects / setter methods. Any consumer will be able to import your producer classes as dependencies, deserialize the message, then immediately know what fields are available. You are not guaranteed to get the latest schema here - you will be "downgraded" and limited to whatever schema was used to generate those classes.

I use `avro-maven-plugin` to generally create the classes. [Just as this example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer)

You could also use [`AvroReflect` to build an Avro schema](https://gist.github.com/jghoman/9641b0f9e3218c195801#file-testavroreflection-java-L42) from a Java class rather than the other way around. [Annotations can be used](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/package-summary.html) on fields to set `@Union` or `@AvroDefault` settings.

[Further Reading about using the Confluent Schema Registry](https://medium.com/@stephane.maarek/introduction-to-schemas-in-apache-kafka-with-the-confluent-schema-registry-3bf55e401321)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So in my case as schema gets changed frequently I need to use GenericRecord approach to make sure that latest schema is available for producer and consumer. Can you please provide one example for GenearicRecord method if possible.

Comment: Same repo as the first link. Go up a directory for the other consumer example

Comment: An important point, though. You need to re-write your code anyway to even get a newer field, so really there should be no major difference to which option if you are in full control of the schema yourself.

Comment: When we use schema registry with avro serialization, do we have any other option in such way that no need of any code change when schema changes.

Comment: Can we use avro tools to create classes based on the latest schema available.

Comment: If the schema changes, you are required to update the code to parse whatever fields you add/change... Your Avro tools will always generate the latest schema if you use the Maven plugin, as documented on the Avro website

Comment: @cricket_007  I genuinely love reading your posts on kafka, always useful! 
I use SpecifcRecord with debezium and have been running into errors where the latest schema is not being used. Switching to GenericRecord seems to big a task with whats already done. (not a Java programmer, and want to avoid POJOs). If I create all debezium topics and their schema subjects, with schemas using namespaces I control. Then I start debezium and it should hopefully use the existing schemas instead of generating new ones with the server, database and table name as namespace?

Comment: @Daniel Haven't used Debezium, but yeah, when using Specific records you're basically stuck with that version until you update the class. But I would expect that to work the same with generic records. You need to recompile code that reads new fields